# Where is the NuGet fallback folder for .NET Core stored in Windows?

Tags: .net-core

I am running .NET Core SDK 2.1, and I discovered that there are two folders in my machine named `NuGetFallbackFolder`. One is stored in `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder`, while the other is in `C:\Users\user\.dotnet\NuGetFallbackFolder`. Each folder weighs about 2 GB, and they contain about the same files.

Are both of these folders needed?

Is one of them a remnant from an older .NET Core release?

Comment: One is system wide and one is user specific. They servce slightly different purposes.

Comment: @DavidG Can you explain the different purposes?

Comment: @omajid Well the system wide cache is usable by anyone who logs on to the computer whereas the user specific one will only cache packages for that user.